# Shouldn't apt-get modify $PATH?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I just installed `libmariadb-java` (JDBC connector). From what I understand, now I am supposed to manually add the jar from */usr/share/java* to the *$PATH* variable - so it's added to CLASSPATH when running any Java program (I know I can probably attached the jar to each program individually, but let's say I want it to by there by default).

This isn't really convenient, it took me some time to realize.

So my question is: isn't apt-get able to upgrade the *$PATH* itself, so the user doesn't need to do it in case as mine? Shouldn't it do it for simplicity?

Comment: I would suggest to file a bug report for a feature request and have the maintainers respond to it. You are asking for our opinion and the answer to your question would be a yes or a no. I also doubt apt would be resposible for it as t would require the maintainer of `libmariadb-java` to arrange this and every other maintainer of software that would like to change PATH. It will get very very very messy quickly if every install would add something to path. Dangerous too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `apt-get` should NOT "modify `$PATH`".

Installing software is one thing, choosing to use the software (by placing its directory in `$PATH`) is another.

`$PATH` is a per-process variable, usually set in `$HOME/.bashrc`. Would you have `apt-get` edit my `$HOME/.bashrc` or figure out how I set my particular `PATH`? Would you have `apt-get` change other processes' `PATH`? NO, No, no!